# Why HTML5 can detect exactly the geographic location?

Tags: html, geolocation, geo

As I know the information about geographic location that a browser has, is from IP. But with an IP, we can only obtain the location like city, country.

I wonder why HTML5 can find my exact street name, like what this page does: http://html5demos.com/geo

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641948/how-html5-geolocation-feature-works

Comment: The page you linked to doesn't show exact location in every situation - I

Comment: possible duplicate of [About Geolocation in HTML 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248404/about-geolocation-in-html-5)

Comment: that's a few blocks away from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it doesn't. It makes an educated guess. But the page you link is several kilometers off for me. And that's despite the fact that my browser *does* know my address (Opera has it as part of settings).