# Google Maps - methods to locate the user

Tags: android, google-maps, localization, maps

It's my first question here. I think that is fine.

I would like to know how to google maps determines the user's location? 
I know that it uses the location of GPS, triangulation and the nearest wi-fi network.

But which method is first used? Whether they are used all? Other methods?

Thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: what u asking, how to find user's location or internal maps process ?

Comment: There is a related topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37894741/how-does-google-map-location-works. Give a look at.

Answer (score 0):

They probably use `FusedLocationProviderApi` https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi

It abstracts dealing with GPS/Mobile/WiFi which is managed automatically depending on available sources, accuracy and accuracy request.