# Identifying user's location based not on IP

Tags: php, javascript, localization, location, ip

I know how can I determine user's location using IP number. However, I'm wondering if there is some more precise technique. I've seen that some applications, eg. Google MAPS, are asking a user for permission to get his location. Is there some kind of such API? Am I missing something?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only generally available, more exact method known to me is the [HTML 5 geolocation API](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html). That API can sometimes fetch a more exact location by scanning nearby wireless networks and their IDs, or querying a GPS device attached to the computer (or as @Pascal says, a GPS device built into a mobile device like an iPhone).

This however works only if the computer has the right hardware, and requires explicit consent from the user.

For user-consent-free, server-side geolocation, the IP-based method is still the best you can do.

See this question for a great rundown on how it works: [About Geolocation in HTML 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248404/about-geolocation-in-html-5)

Answer (score 1):

That would be the [geolocation API](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html).

Answer (score 1):

See the [Geolocation API](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/) and the matching section of [Dive into HTML 5](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html)

Answer (score 1):

Some devices *(typically, smartphones)* have a GPS -- which means quite precise location -- or can use wifi / cell-towers / ...

You cannot get that location on the server (it's not sent by the browser), but you could get it from Javascript *(and, then, send it to the server, using some Ajax)*.

For some documentation, you can take a look at :

- [**W3C Geolocation API**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/W3C_Geolocation_API)
- And [**Using geolocation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_geolocation) *(which applies at least to Firefox >= 3.5)*

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be problems with GeoLocation in HTML5 http://ipgeo5.com/

Yesterday I was in Montreal and worked perfectly pinpointing my current location to the nearest 30 feet(estimate).  Running Windows XP, Chrome 14.0.835.

Today, I am at my mom's house in a small town in Ontario, Canada and getting this error.

---

Your Current Location
We have estimated you are located at 
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$AdministrativeArea in /var/www/ipgeo5.com/pages/city.php on line 29

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/ipgeo5.com/pages/city.php on line 29
 , , Canada  by using HTML 5 Geolocation technique.
Your location:

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$AdministrativeArea in /var/www/ipgeo5.com/pages/city.php on line 29

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/ipgeo5.com/pages/city.php on line 29

### , , Canada

So I guess this is not 100% effective !

So needs to have Plan B using IP2Location database to identify location.

Thanks !

Michel, Montreal, Canada